# Dynamic value from input in datatables url

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, datatables, thymeleaf

I have a datatable inside a modal form and I need load it dynamically in serverside, I have a input where I catch value and need to send it via javascript (or other method different than get it from modelAttribute object)to load the table.

this is the datatable, I need the value stored in `#idCProp` input

```
<table th:if="${entity.formulario == 'formPerson'}" class="table dataTable" dt:deferLoading="10" id="propDT" dt:reloadSelector="#reloadProponent"  dt:table="true"  dt:sortable="true" dt:displaylength="10" dt:dom='ftip' dt:url="@{/person/loadProponents/__${entity.id}__/ **VALUE FROM INPUT**}" dt:serverside="true">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th dt:property="entity.id" dt:renderFunction="nameAndLastName">Persona</th>
        <th dt:property="entity.id" dt:sortable="false" dt:renderFunction="getProposalPost">Cargo</th>
        <th dt:property="entity.id" dt:sortable="false" dt:renderFunction="getProposalInstitution">Institución</th>
        <th dt:property="sendMethod.name" dt:sortable="false">M&eacute;todo de env&iacute;o</th>
        <th class="operations" dt:sortable="false" dt:property="id" dt:renderFunction="idToUrlProp"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="idCProp"/>
```

and this is the controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person/loadProponents/{idPerson}/{idCandidature}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody DatatablesResponse<Proposal> loadProponents(@PathVariable("idPerson") Long idPerson,@PathVariable("idCandidature") String idCandidature,
            @DatatablesParams DatatablesCriterias criterias, HttpServletRequest request) {
   //Do some stuff...
}
```

How can I send `idCandidature` variable?

Comment: Maybe @tduchateau can help you...

Comment: Have you tried anyway to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the better way it's using [dataTables API](https://datatables.net/manual/api) and `request` variables to do it.

Your view code would be :

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <input type="hidden" id="idCProp"/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" 
       th:text="#{proposals.find}" 
       onclick="findProposals();"></button>

</form>
<table th:if="${entity.formulario == 'formPerson'}" class="table dataTable" dt:deferLoading="10" id="propDT" dt:reloadSelector="#reloadProponent"  dt:table="true"  dt:sortable="true" dt:displaylength="10" dt:dom='ftip' dt:url="@{/person/loadProponents/__${entity.id}__}" dt:serverside="true">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th dt:property="entity.id" dt:renderFunction="nameAndLastName">Persona</th>
    <th dt:property="entity.id" dt:sortable="false" dt:renderFunction="getProposalPost">Cargo</th>
    <th dt:property="entity.id" dt:sortable="false" dt:renderFunction="getProposalInstitution">Institución</th>
    <th dt:property="sendMethod.name" dt:sortable="false">M&eacute;todo de env&iacute;o</th>
    <th class="operations" dt:sortable="false" dt:property="id" dt:renderFunction="idToUrlProp"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>


<script th:inline="javascript">
    function findProposals() {
        oTable_propDT.columns(2).search($("#idCProp").val());
        ... // more parameters if you need
        oTable_propDT.columns(n).search($("#yoursearchparameterfrominput").val());
        oTable_propDT.draw();
    }
</script>
```

In your controller you already have everything you need :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person/loadProponents/{idPerson}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody DatatablesResponse<Proposal> loadProponents(@PathVariable("idPerson") Long idPerson, HttpServletRequest request) {
   DatatablesCriterias criterias = DatatablesCriterias.getFromRequest(request);
   DataSet<Proposal> dataset = proposalService.getProposalsDataset(criterias);
   return DatatablesResponse.build(dataset, criterias);
}
```

Finally you just need to write `proposalService#getProposalsDataset(DatatablesCriterias criterias)` method that builds `Dataset`, I think it's nothing special.